# Rails - Using twitter oAuth for logging in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-authorization

I use Twitter oAuth to allow users to signup for my site.

I have the user's access_token, access_secret from their signup stored.

When the user wants to return to the site and login to their account, how do I authenticate them using twitter login/password?

I do not want to ask users to give access like:
     - give access to example.com to read/write your stuff on twitter

The user already has signed up using their twitter credentials, how do I reuse it instead of asking them to create a separate password?

I would rather not venture towards authlogic in addition to oauth

Currently, if the user is already logged into twitter, I can authenticate him.
using the access_token, access_secret. What if he is not logged in? 
How do I prompt for username/password for twitter and authenticate for my app?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why dont you use omniauth ? http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using them [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem. Makes doing that pretty straight forward.

If you're not wanting another gem dependency, you could probably code up your own functionality based on what they do with their [twitter strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb) and [abstract oauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-oauth/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb) logic.

Answer (score 0):

[This RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth) episode demonstrates how to create a simple authentication system that only requires an OAuth verification, without the need for a seperate user account maintained by your app.